# Bluetooth Low Energy is dropping characteristics

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am currently working with a Bluetooth Low Energy device for work. On some phones I can stream data and the signals from our peripheral come in just fine. In other phones on the other hand several characteristics are dropped while streaming and the app does not work properly. This is mostly the case with Samsung phones. Any idea why Android Phones might drop characteristic values and how I might be able to get around this issue ?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "dropping characteristics"?   I am using GATT characteristics, and I've noticed some issues in Android (on Samsung devices) that I don't see on iOS.  Two examples -- not delivering a characteristic  change, and having a characteristic change come back as a notification (echoed), but only occaisionally.  Also, what BLE module on the peripheral?  We see this on Microchip RN4020.

Comment: @bobwki by dropping characteristics I mean that none of the data in the 60 bytes you can get from the peripheral are received from the phone. Btw this peripheral works perfect for me on iOS as well

Comment: I wish I had more experience on Android phones.  I have been using Notifications to get data from characteristics, on  both iOS & Android. I have the impression that a characteristic has a limited size, but I think I've run up against this more on the module side, not on the phone side.  Are you putting 60 bytes in at one time?  I've seen several things indicating 20 bytes at a time.  Don't know why iOS would work better.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry for my bad english

Samsung devices usually have different characteristics, for example I'm using text to spech in my own android project, but samsung s7 doesn't sound at all. I think the root of the device